# Check if a string has only white spaces in it

Tags: regex, r, string, if-statement, whitespace

How to check if a string has only white spaces in it?

I want to use the condition in `if()` statement.

For example,

```
str<-"     " 
#check if str has only white spaces? example usage 
if(str != empty)...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `trimws`, which removes leading/trailing white-space from a character string:

```
trimws(str) == ""
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, This helped ;)

Comment: Never heard of this function.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think it was introduced in a pretty recent R version. It's just some regex internally.

Comment: 3.2.0 more specifically.

Comment: This function trimws is now in the base package. Before 3.2.0, this function    can be found in the memisc package.

Answer (score 4):

I usually resort to regex for this kind of thing. `grepl` returns logical if the regex matches or not.

```
grepl("^\\s*$", str)
# [1] TRUE
```

Here is a short explanation of the regex `^\\s*$`

1. `^`    - Start of string
2. `\\s*` - Zero or more whitespace characters
3. `$` - end of string

So in worlds that would translate to: only match strings that have zero or more whitespace characters between start and end of string.

Comment: You should replace `+` with `*` to return `TRUE` with empty strings too.

Comment: Ok. I didn't interpret the question that way. I thought the question was if there were whitespaces in the string. But looking at the other answer I guess you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer is given right. But, want to post a very simple method of string to check if the string has only white spaces in it.

```
const str = "        ";
const isValidString = (str) => str.trim().length === 0 ? false : true;
isValidString(str);
```

Happy coding :)